Convert numeric data to times and back again
I have a large dataset with a 'time' column containing the lubridate 'Period' time format, ie 'xH yM zS, for example 3H 30M 0S. All of the data is in fractions of an hour, the smallest fraction is 15min, most are either on the hour or half past. Is there a way to convert these to simple numerals, so 3H 30M 0S becomes 3.5.
Furthermore, is there a way to take a numeric value like 2.75 and convert it to 2H 45M 0S?
I do not want, need, or have associated date information.
Lubridate appears to only work with integers.

Please read about how to make a great R reproducible example and update your question accordingly. Include a sample of your data by pasting the output of dput(<your data frame>) into your post or dput(head(<your data frame>)) if you have a large data frame. If you cannot post your data, then post code for creating representative data. Also include code you have tried, any relevant errors, and expected output.

1) lubridate If we have a character string we can convert it to Period class, p, using as.period and from there:

as.numeric will convert it to numeric.  (To convert back to Period convert the hours to seconds and then use as.duration followed by as.period.)
as.character can convert a Period object to character.

See code below
library (lubridate)
 
p <- as.period("3H 30M 0S"); p
## [1] "3H 30M 0S"
class(p)
## [1] "Period"
attr(,"package")
[1] "lubridate"

x <- as.numeric(p, "hours"); x
## [1] 3.5

as.period(as.duration(3600*x))
## [1] "3H 30M 0S"

as.character(p)
## [1] "3H 30M 0S"

2) Base R Using only base R we can parse an input string of the form shown using read.table and from that compute the hours, hrs. To go back in the other direction we convert to POSIXlt and the use sprintf with the individual POSIXlt components.
ch <- "3H 30M 0S"

df1 <- read.table(text = gsub("[HMS]", "", ch))
hrs <- with(df1, V1 + V2/60 + V3/3600); hrs
## [1] 3.5

lt <- as.POSIXlt(3600 * hrs, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")
with(lt, sprintf("%dH %dM %dS", hour, min, sec))
## [1] "3H 30M 0S"


Here is a solution with chron::times based on answers to this SO question.
num2hour  <- function(x) chron::times(hr_dec/24)
hour2num  <- function(x) {
  x |>
    gsub("H|M", ":", x = _) |>
    sub("S", "", x = _) |>
    chron::times() |>
    (\(x) as.numeric(x) * 24)()
}

hr_dec <- c(3.5, 2.75)
hr <- c("3H 30M 0S", "2H 45M 0S")

num2hour(hr_dec)
#> [1] 03:30:00 02:45:00
hour2num(hr)
#> [1] 3.50 2.75

Created on 2024-05-14 with reprex v2.1.0
